# Как подключить статичную страницу php в файле index.php, чтобы она была доступна по ссылке?

Tags: wordpress, ссылки

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста!

Такое дело. Пишу тему wordpress, допустим, у меня меню в хедере, и в нем мне надо подключить страницу с уникальной версткой - я создаю файл с этой версткой с расширением .php и через `<a></a>` подключаю в index.php, файл лежит в этой же папке, что и index.php, но ничего не получается. (

**Обновление**

Это меню в index.php `<ul><li><a href="ссылка на файл.php"></a></li></ul>`,
а подключаемый файл лежит в этой же папке, что и index.php.
В общем, в index.php у меня меню, и нужно, чтоб я кликнул по ссылке в меню и перешел на файл.php с уникальной версткой.

Comment: Можно пример, а то не очень понятно, что Вы там "подключаете". (pastebin.com)

Comment: это меню в index.php <ul><li><a href="ссылка на файл.php"></a></li></ul>
а подключаемый файл лежит в этой же папке что и index.php, в общем в index.php у меня меню и нужно чтоб я кликнул по ссылке в меню и перешел на файл.php с уникальной версткой